# Select method of ObjectDataSource called before update button

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, datalist

I have got a datalist with ObjectDataSource , The issue is when i call the update method , the selectmethod of  datalist is executed before the update method, which in result doesnt shows the updated datalist , i have to f5 to see the updated results, below is the code:

AspView

```
<asp:DataList ID="CustomersDefaultPaging" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    RepeatColumns="1" EnableViewState="False" 
    DataSourceID="CustomersDefaultPagingDataSource" DataKeyField="Id">
    <ItemTemplate>.....</ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CustomersDefaultPagingDataSource" runat="server"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetCustomersAsPagedDataSource"
        TypeName="mobilecustomers" 
    OnSelected="CustomersDefaultPagingDataSource_Selected">
```

CodeBehind

```
     protected void CustomersDefaultPagingDataSource_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    // Reference the PagedDataSource bound to the DataList
    PagedDataSource pagedData = (PagedDataSource)e.ReturnValue;

    // Remember the total number of records being paged through across postbacks
    TotalRowCount = pagedData.DataSourceCount;

    // Configure the paging interface based on the data in the PagedDataSource
    FirstPage.Enabled = !pagedData.IsFirstPage;
    PrevPage.Enabled = !pagedData.IsFirstPage;
    NextPage.Enabled = !pagedData.IsLastPage;
    LastPage.Enabled = !pagedData.IsLastPage;

    // Display the current page being viewed...
    CurrentPageNumber.Text = string.Format("You are viewing page {0} of {1}...", PageIndex + 1, PageCount);
}

     protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in CustomersDefaultPaging.Items)
    {
        customers.UpdateCustomerAddress(.........);


    }
}
```

DataAcess

```
      static public DataTable GetAllCustomers()
     {

    string sql = "Select * from [Customers] where [Upgrade] = 0";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
    }

      public PagedDataSource GetCustomersAsPagedDataSource(string sortExpression, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = GetAllCustomers();
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression;
    // Limit the results through a PagedDataSource
    PagedDataSource pagedData = new PagedDataSource();
    pagedData.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    //pagedData.DataBind();
    pagedData.AllowPaging = true;
    pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = pageIndex;
    pagedData.PageSize = pageSize;
    return pagedData;
}
```

On update click the datalist should display only customers whose upgrade value is 0, Curretly when i update the field to 0 it update the sql db but it doesnt shows on the datalist i have to refresh it in order to see the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `DataList` doesn't do it's own rebinding. I don't know if this would work but what about hooking into the DataList `Updated` event and forcing the grid to Bind there. Could that help?

From what I've read the `GridView` control plays a lot nicer with the `ObjectDataSource`. It it were me I might be tempted to swap out the `DataList` for a `GridView` and see if that helps. Or at least run some quick tests and see.

All a bit vague admittedly